# Ruby on Rails won't refresh page with link to #googtrans(en|TARGET_LANG_CODE)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, translate

I am trying to link my own app to the same page, but have it add #googtrans(en|fr) or some other language code to the end of the link so google will render it as a different language. It will work if it is going to a different page in the site, but for some reason if it goes to the same page it won't refresh. I have tried several different ways to do it, but so far have not had any success. Right now I have links that say <%= link_to "#googtrans(en|ko)" do %> Link Here <%end%>.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something along the lines of creating a helper method.  Bear in mind I am relatively new to Ruby but I would attempt.

helper_method :translate(language)

def translate(language)

@whatever = params[:whatever]

respond_to do |format|

```
  format.html { redirect_to @whatever_url(language) }

end
```

end

Then link to it with what you want the language to be.

Link Here

I may be way off base but that should get you going in the right direction.  That way when you link to it, it will push it through an action that should refresh the page.

Comment: I think the problem is either getting it to redirect or to get it to follow a URL with # in it. I can either get it to place the proper URL in the navigation bar, but it won't refresh with that in it to go to the new URL.